# hibernate many-to-many prevent child deletion

Tags: java, hibernate

Im currently working with `hibernate` and `java`. I have a `Group` class and a `User` class. They have an many to many relation as users can be in multiple groups and groups can have multiple users. You can see a part of our `ERD` here: [ERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PSbZ.png).

The part of the `Group` class where I define the relation:

```
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "Group_Users", catalog = "jelo3", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "Group_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "User_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) })
    public Set<User> getAllGroupMembers() {
        return this.allGroupMembers;
    }
```

The part of the where I delete the group:

```
    @Override
    public void delete(int id) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Group g = (Group) session.get(Group.class, id);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        if (g != null) {
            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.delete(g);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        }
    }
```

**Observation**: The problem is that when I delete a group all the users that are in the group also are deleted.

**Actual Requirement**: When I delete the group all the records in the link table should be deleted, but the users should not be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` from `Group` to `User`, which means that delete operation called on the group will be cascaded to all users in the group. When working with bidirectional mappings, you need to maintain both sides of the relationship.

When you get the `Group` from database, go through its users and remove the group from their groups list. After that, remove users from group. Something like this

```
    if (g != null) {
        session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        for (User u : g.getUsers()) {
            u.getGroups().remove(g);
        }
        g.getUsers().clear();
        session.delete(g);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`DELETE ON CASCADE` can be configured in the DDL to delete Children while deleting Parent or  `CascadeType` enum in hibernate mapping to be defined